# Wireless on Medion MD96500 (Intel® PRO/Wireless 2200BG) running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I just installed Windows 7 (32 bit) on a Medion MD96500 (Intel 2200BG Wireless Card) and then installed the Windows Vista (32 bit) driver.
Now, in the "device driver window", the Wireless Card is listed as working/active.

If I want to set up a wireless connection, however, I always get the error message

> No connections available

Pushing the hardware-switch (or however that thing is called, right next to the keyboard) does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The Keys next to the Keyboard are not only "Quick Launch Buttons" but ALSO a hardware activation. One way to activate wireless is to set it in the bios as always running, the other is to get the newest Quick Launch Manager (currently 1.3.6) for Vista, it works flawless on Windows 7.
Medion should not have Hardware activation buttons that need to use software. Doh!

Comment: well done :) +1

Answer (score 1):

http://www1.medion.de/downloads/?op=search&lang=de&type=TEXT&Param=

Medion Launch Manger for MD 97900 also works on MD 97500

Answer (score 0):

this is not "hardware switch" but a 'Quick Launch Button' and you'll need to install the **Launch Manager** software to use any of these 4 keys.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I was wondering how to get the wireless up and running. I have tried both the xp and the Vista driver, and yes the card is listed as working and active, but no networks seem to be found this far.